# when I try to concatenate a string within a JSTL tag. An error occur

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jstl

```
str += "<td><fmt:formatDate value='"+notices[i].noticeDuration+"' type='date' dateStyle='default' pattern='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' /></td>";
```

I am trying to concatenate a string, and append it to the body. Due to the JSTL tag---fmt, an error occurs. It said I lost a quotation. I tried to figure out why it happened, with no luck.

Comment: notices[i].noticeDuration should be a java variable. JSTL run server side. Or you can format the date using javascript.

Comment: I'm sorry.Don't really understand what's your mean.Could you pls kindly explain it in detail? Really thanks.

Comment: this like, JSP compiler see notices[i].noticeDuration as string, not date value. because notices[i].noticeDuration run client (browser). So, you can't use js variable in jstl tags.

Comment: Really thanks.I have fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, JSP compiler will see `notices[i].noticeDuration` as string as is, not date value. Because notices[i].noticeDuration run client (browser). So, you can't use JS variable in JSTL tags.